# Im making a room in the basement and have a problem with framing

Tags: basement, framing

There is a room in my mother-in-law's basement which was partially framed a long time ago and I was wanting to finish it. The problem is there is an exterior wall which sticks out and then back in and there is a rigid pipe going along the bottom of it so I am unsure how I should frame along this.
The pictures explain it better .
Any ideas would be much appreciated. [image]

Comment: Can you please point out where in the photo the pipe is?

Comment: Also, please don't leave your hammer on top of the ladder like that.  Been there done that, still got the scar.

Comment: The pipe is actually conduit. It runs below the window.

Comment: I was thinking to just make a frame in front of the wall all the way up

Comment: The conduit is the one you can see coming from the water main on the left side of the picture